# javascript show or hide when option is changed

Tags: javascript

so i am trying to show or hide with javascript when option value K is pressed. When K is pressed `div class "nobr"` will appear. when option value K is not pressed "nobr" is hidden.

```
<select name="item[1502][additional_data] scustomg" style="width: 100%" onchange="setCustomPrice(1502, $(this))" id="select-custom-group">
<option value="1" data-price="300.0000">1 - €300.00</option>
<option value="2" data-price="210.0000">2 - €210.00</option>
<option value="4" data-price="189.0000">4 - €189.00</option>
<option value="6" data-price="210.0000">6 - €210.00</option>
<option value="8" data-price="210.0000">8 - €210.00</option>
<option value="9" data-price="0.0000">9 - €0.00</option>
<option value="K" data-price="0.0000">K - €0.00</option>
</select>

<div class="nobr">
<input type="checkbox" id="item_use_custom_price_1502" onclick="order.toggleCustomPrice(this, 'item_custom_price_1502', 'item_tier_block_1502');">
<label class="normal" for="item_use_custom_price_1502">Custom Price*</label>
</div>
```

I can get Javascript work and i See pop up box. but can get this when K is pressed.

```
<script>
var card = document.getElementById("select-custom-group");
if(card.selectedValue == "8") {
     alert('select one answer');
}
else {
    var selectedText = card.options[card.selectedIndex].text;
    alert("Test");
}
</script>
```

Comment: can be more clear on your question and post. and provide a fiddle

Comment: Possible for you to give your `nobr` div an `id`? Either that or you will need to target the correct index for that class element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with javascript you can add onchange function having the selected option as parameter, then check if the value is your required value, if it is the case then hide the div else show the div

```html
<select name="item[1502][additional_data] scustomg" style="width: 100%" onchange="setCustomPrice('price_info_1', this)" id="select-custom-group">
<option value="1" data-price="">Pick a Price</option>
<option value="1" data-price="300.0000">1 - €300.00</option>
<option value="2" data-price="210.0000">2 - €210.00</option>
<option value="4" data-price="189.0000">4 - €189.00</option>
<option value="6" data-price="210.0000">6 - €210.00</option>
<option value="8" data-price="210.0000">8 - €210.00</option>
<option value="9" data-price="0.0000">9 - €0.00</option>
<option value="K" data-price="0.0000">K - €0.00</option>
</select>

<div class="nobr" id="price_info_1" style="display:none">
<input type="checkbox"  onclick="">
<label class="normal" for="item_use_custom_price_1502">Custom Price*</label>
</div>
<br/>
<select name="item[1502][additional_data] scustomg" style="width: 100%" onchange="setCustomPrice('price_info_2', this)" id="select-custom-group">
<option value="1" data-price="">Pick a Price</option>
<option value="1" data-price="300.0000">1 - €300.00</option>
<option value="2" data-price="210.0000">2 - €210.00</option>
<option value="4" data-price="189.0000">4 - €189.00</option>
<option value="6" data-price="210.0000">6 - €210.00</option>
<option value="8" data-price="210.0000">8 - €210.00</option>
<option value="9" data-price="0.0000">9 - €0.00</option>
<option value="K" data-price="0.0000">K - €0.00</option>
</select>

<div class="nobr" id="price_info_2" style="display:none">
<input type="checkbox"  onclick="">
<label class="normal" for="item_use_custom_price_1502">Custom Price*</label>
</div>
    
    <script>
function setCustomPrice(div_to_toggle,selected){  
      if(selected.value=="K") document.getElementById(div_to_toggle).style.display = 'none';
      else document.getElementById(div_to_toggle).style.display = 'block';
     }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks man this is working. but only thing missing. when nothing is selected at beginning you cant see as well the custom price. now when i open it i can tick custom price. when i change to 8 the custom price is hidden. and i found another issue. i have more products with this custom price if I change to K it changes on all of them.  see on screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwweON8IpmfWZHR6emdqQjZQMFk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: See Update: you can in onchange function indicate the div id you want to hide as paramter.

Comment: how do i do this ? can you help me please

Comment: I have already updated my answer, if you have problems you can post your fiddle code in a comment.

Comment: dont know how to add fiddle. please check screenshot. its not working.

Comment: dont know how to add fiddle here. please check screenshot. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwweON8IpmfWeU1PRGFFRTBIalk/view?usp=sharing . code what i am using 

<script>
function setCustomPrice(div_to_toggle,selected){  
      if(selected.value=="K") document.getElementById(div_to_toggle).style.display = 'block';
      else document.getElementById(div_to_toggle).style.display = 'none';
     }
</script>

error in inspector: 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Comment: thanks man! now its working fine only thing is that is showing when nothing is selected. I want to hide this option and show only when K is pressed.  you have different way but I swap none and display. thank you very much

Comment: ok i solved it. but now when I change one product to K and change the price to Custom price and hit Update the price and quantity in Magento it change all products to K which is 0. see attached. :( https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwweON8IpmfWTkdDcXlNWjFfWHc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: so when i change group and update it doesnt save the price at all. this site make me sick :(

Comment: can you open a new clear question ,because I could not understand you what do you need.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need to listen to the change of the dropdown.

with jQuery, you can do

```
$('#select-custom-group').change(function () {
  $('.nobr ').toggle($(this).val() === 'K');
});
```